Polynomial Kernel For Minimum Maximal Matching Problem
Let $G$ be a graph, and $k$ be some non-negative integer. The goal is to decide whether there exists a maximal matching in $G$ on at most $k$ edges. This problem is also asked in https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf as exercise 2.7 (page 40). Together with the hints provided for the problem (page 44), I got the following results
Searching for such a matching of $\leq k$ edges, is equivalent to finding a vertex cover of $\leq 2k$ vertices. If any vertex has degree $> 2k$, then that vertex has to be in the solution. If we consider the set of vertices of degree $> 2k$ as $X$, then $G - X$ is a graph where any vertex is of degree $\leq 2k$. A yes-solution has $\leq k$ such that those edges are disjoint w.r.t. vertices they touch.
After this I am stuck. I would really appreciate any help.

Why do you think that searching for a maximal matching of at most $k$ edges is equivalent to a searching for a vertex cover of at most $2k$ vertices? Consider $G = C_4$ and $k = 1$. There is a vertex cover with cardinality $2$, while there is no maximal matching of cardinality $1$.
